# mvc 4 radiobuttonfor binding with model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I am validating radiobuttonfor with data annotations. making it a required in model. but it's not working. below is my code.

In view.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsMedicalInsurance, true, new { id="rdhaveinsu"}) Yes           
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsMedicalInsurance, false, new { id="rdhavenoinsu"})No
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsMedicalInsurance)
```

In Model.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="Please update about medical insurance")]
 public bool IsMedicalInsurance { set; get; }
```

Comment: Whats not working? Its a `boolean` property and your selecting either `true` or `false` which means its valid for either one.

Comment: I want to show error message when there is no selection. for this I have make it required. but getting no error message why?

Comment: What do you mean _when there is no selection_? There are only 2 radio buttons in the group and one of them will be always be selected so the value of `IsMedicalInsurance` will be either `true` or `false`

Comment: by default there is no button is selected?

Comment: Of course there is - that's the default behavior (unless it's `bool?`). If the value of `IsMedicalInsurance` is `true`, then the first one will be selected, if its `false` then the second one will be selected

Comment: How to change it that by default no selection of radio button?

Comment: Make the property nullable `public bool? IsMedicalInsurance { set; get; }`